# How to search by nested field id using NativeSearchQueryBuilder in ElasticsearchRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using `spring-data-elasticsearch` and I have a class as follows,

```
@Document(indexName = "sample")
class Sample {

   @Id
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private Status status;
}

class Status {
   private String id;
}
```

Above is persisted to `elasticsearch`. And I have the following method to find data in it.

```
List<Sample> getAll(String statusId, String text, Pageable pageable);
```

So here is the current code I am using to get the data,

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(text)
                        .field("name")
                        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX));
NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
```

What I need is I need to find results by `statusId` and then search for the texts containing in `name` field.

I tried the following way also but didn't work. I tried the `criteria-api` also but it is working for only words without space. If there is words with space it is throwing `Cannot constructQuery '*\"text\"*'. Use expression or multiple clauses instead`

`.withFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("status.id", statusId))`

So how can I build the query for the above scenario?

New query build after suggestions by [P.J. Meisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393565/p-j-meisch)

```
QueryBuilder query1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status.id", statusId).operator(Operator.AND);
QueryBuilder query2 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(text).field("name").type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);

new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(query1).must(query2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top level query should be a *bool* query with two entries as *must*:

- the first for the `name` that would be the one you already have.
- the second for the "status.id" property

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.